# No CUDA option in repository version of Blender

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

I know there are a lot of threads concerning CUDA and GPU-rendering in Blender, but I haven't figured out yet why my installed Blender(2.70) from the repository offers no choice of the rendering-hardware but the bundle you get from blender.org does?

I'm currently using Linux Mint 16 64bit but I observed that fact on Ubuntu 12.04 as well. But on Ubuntu 14.04 the CUDA-option is active on both versions of Blender.

So my system has the necessary drivers to go on with the GPU, the question is, where do I start to fix the repository version, cause I'd like to link the blend-files..

Comment: It's possible the package maintainers simply aren't building with CUDA enabled.. If the blender.org version works, is there reason you can't use that?

Comment: I had that same issue (and others) when installing 2.7 form repository on Linux Mint 16. The http://www.blender.org/download/ works fine.

Comment: @gandalf3: As I mentioned in the last paragraph, I don't know how to link files to not installed programmes like the bundle from blender.org. To open a programm, then selecting files isn't my typical workflow...^^

Comment: Using most file managers you should be able to right click and define a path to an executable to open any files of that type. However "how to specify what program opens a file in x filemanager" isn't really related to blender anymore.. You might try on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just made an install of Linux Mint 16 64bit (with the Mate window manager) and have Blender3D working with CUDA.

Here is what did:
1: After installation of Linux Mint 16 64bit I did an update (many files)
2: Reboot.
3: Enabled the proprietary Nvidia-driver
4: With the Software Manager I installed the CUDA Toolkit (nvidia-cuda-toolkit)
5: Reboot.
6: Install Blender 3D
7: In Blender 3D CUDA was now available.

I'm not sure if nr.4 and nr.6 can be switched ... but you can try.